# @Autowire Not Setting DAO

Tags: java, spring

I have the following Spring Java configuration set up:

```
@Configuration
public class FooConfig {
    @Autowired
    private IReferenceDataDAO referenceDataDAO;

    @Bean
    public IReferenceDataService getReferenceDataService() {
        return new ReferenceDataServiceImpl(referenceDataDAO);
    }
}
```

I am trying to reference the **ReferenceDataService** bean in another configuration class using the @Autowire property:

```
@Configuration
public class BarConfig {

    @Autowired
    private IRuleService ruleService;

    @Autowired
    private IReferenceDataService referenceDataService;
}
```

Here is the config that defines the IReferenceDataDAO:

```
@Configuration
public class FooBarConfig {

@Bean
public IReferenceDataDAO getReferenceDataDAO() {
    return new ReferenceDataDAOImpl(getStaticData(), getMapper());
    }
}
```

Here is the ReferenceDataServiceImpl:

```
public class ReferenceDataServiceImpl implements IReferenceDataService {

   private IReferenceDataDAO dao;

public ReferenceDataServiceImpl(IReferenceDataDAO dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}
```

The above configs are imported in a master config class:

```
@Configuration
@Import({
    FoosAppConfig.class,
BarAppConfig.class,
FooBarAppConfig.class,
})
```

I am noticing that this configuration leads to the **referenceDAO** in the **ReferenceDataServiceImpl** being set to null.  What am I doing wrong?  Shouldn't that @Autowire annotation ensure that my bean is fully configured before setting it?

Comment: Can we see `ReferenceDataServiceImpl`...?

Comment: And where is `IReferenceDataDAO` defined as a bean?

Comment: You can autowire in configuration??

Comment: @Bart Thanks :) I learned something

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. I added fragments for the service and DAO.

Answer (score 0):

BarConfig needs to import FooConfig
@Import({ FooConfig.class })

Comment: Why? What would that do?

Comment: BarConfig and FooConfig are two separate spring configuration. They do not share any information. If you want to use Beans from FooConfig in BarConfig then you have to import FooConfig into BarConfig. This allows BarConfig to know about beans in FooConfig

Comment: And which beans does `BarConfig` define that `FooConfig` needs?

Comment: Actually, this is what I am doing.  I have a third config, that imports all necessary configuration files.

Comment: Is fooConfig imported before BarConfig?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ FooConfig.class })
public class BarConfig {

    @Autowired
    private IRuleService ruleService;

    @Autowired
    private IReferenceDataService referenceDataService;
}
```

This allows BarConfig to get access to the IReferenceDataService bean.